# Can't save an API as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, atom-editor

[NETWORK TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhgQN.jpg)With the code I have I want the console log to pass 6983839 to the console but it stays empty the whole time and the page refreshes. The endpoint of the API is [here](https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?name=Tornado%20Dragon). The function is executed by a button press which I'm 99% sure isnt the issue as it works when a change the function to do something else and I have jQuery in my folder for the project aswell and linked in the html file. The code is my JS file is below,

```
 function showCard() {
  var cardName = document.getElementById('un').value;
  var  cardNameProper = cardName.replace(/\s/g,'');
  $.getJSON("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?name=Tornado%20Dragon", null, function(info){
    var result = info["data"][0]["id"]
    console.log(result)
  })

}
```

Also including the HTML code incase its relevant

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

  <style>
  .title{
    color: white;
  }

  .cardSearch{
    text-color: white;
  }

  #searchBox{
    margin-right: 20px;
   }

   #chosenCard{
     width: 177px;
     height: 254px;
   }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="header-img" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card card-body bg-dark">
        <div class="rows">
        <div class="col-ms-8">
          <img src="yugioh.png" class = "img-responsive mx-auto d-block"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-ms-4 text-center">
          <h4 class="title">Combo Builder</h4>
          <div id="searchBox">
            <form id="cardSearch">
              <input type="text" size="12" id="un" />
              <input type="submit" onclick="showCard();" value="Submit Card"/>
            </form>
            <img id="chosenCard" scr="cardBack.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, this function seems to work correctly. The console logs "6983839" so the error must be somewhere else. Usually you preferably put all your related code in the question :)

Comment: sorry ive done that now

Comment: try to remove the brackets and semicolon in the onclick attribute

Comment: No luck with that unfortunatley, when i look at the inspect element inorder to look at the console log i see this "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol." Then when i click submit it goes blank and reloads with the same error

Comment: You're submitting the form. The AJAX request is send from the browser, and after that the pending submission is executed. This will reload your page, as you haven't set anything to `action` attribute. Use a button type of button to run the JS only, without submitting the form.

Comment: tried that the page doesnt reload but still nothing in the console

Comment: As others have already said, [your code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/czyfpoha/).

Comment: what would be different when running it on my own laptop and on fiddle?

Comment: Nothing, open the Network tab, click the button, then you"ll see what is happening.

Comment: im fairly new to all this, nothing changes on the network tab when i press the submit card button, theres one thing listed but its for bootstrap

Comment: Open the Network Settings, and click "Persist Logs", then try. You can do this same at the linked fiddle, open the tab, click "Run", and you'll see the XHR response occuring to the tab. Make also sure you're not filtering anything out from the logging (also in the Console tab).

Comment: Take a look at these two fiddles (open the Network tab). [#1 submits the form](https://jsfiddle.net/eu5y0mvL/), and [#2 doesn't submit](https://jsfiddle.net/eu5y0mvL/1/). The second snippet should work for you too.

Comment: im not sure how to read it, theres a fair amount of CSS warnings but i cant see how that would interfere, ive attached an image of the network with persistent logs on, to the original post

Comment: The tab has to be already opened when you click the submit button.

Comment: yeah ive tried that theres no request to the API showing up

Comment: And no request to your own page either? If that's the case, the onclick never executes your code. Put a log at the beginning of the function, just log "Runs". In the meanwhile, you can read about [inline listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462554/how-does-the-way-in-which-a-javascript-event-handler-is-assigned-affect-its-exec/63119431#63119431).

Comment: It's finally working, i copied in the code from the fiddle and even though i cant see any differences it is working now! Thanks to everyone!