# Ember Octane (3.22+) why use {{on 'click' this.function}} instead of onclick={{this.function}}

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-octane

So in Ember Octane there are two ways of attaching a function to an event in an `hbs` file.

The EmberJS way: `{{on 'click' this.function}}`

Classic HTML way: `onclick={{this.function}}`

[Here they suggest using the prior syntax](https://ember-learn.github.io/ember-octane-vs-classic-cheat-sheet/)

However I don't see a reason why to use that syntax unless we have due reason to do so.

What are the reasons I would use the former over the latter?

Comment: "_Classic HTML way_" is too classic, it's outdated and potentially dangerous.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the response. Can you give me an explanation or link me to some articles explaining why?

Comment: [Here's some points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63119431/1169519) why to avoid inline listeners. "_Potentially dangerous_" means a possible workaround of [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy), as you can't `nonce` mark inline handlers, or evaluate them as secure in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{{on 'click' this.function}}
```

uses `addEventListener` semantics from W3C DOM 1.0 spec and automatically cleans itself up with `removeEventListener` when the template is destroyed.

```
onClick={{this.function}}
```

uses the older DOM event semantics from HTML4, which

1. does not allow multiple listeners
2. does not propagate to outside elements
3. swallows any events from nested elements