# onmousemove Event is not able to pass event-data in JavaScript Example

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In this example, when I move mouse inside a div, I want to show the (x and y co-ordinates) of mouse current position, but it is showing error. Why?

```js
function fifa(ev){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.background = "cornsilk";
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = (ev.clientX + " "  + ev.clientY);
}
```

```css
div {
  height:200px; 
  width:200px; 
  border:2px solid #000; 
  background:green; 
  display:inline-block; 
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onmousemove="fifa(ev)">onmousemove</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63119431/1169519 , what causes the error is explained in Often misunderstood behavior chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is you are trying to pass the unknown variable `ev` - it does not exist. You can pass (event) as they do [at the site you used](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove):  `myFunction(event)`

I strongly recommend to change to eventListener and also to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) over w3schools

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1'); // cache the element
// only change colour once, using class
div1.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  this.classList.add("silk")
})
div1.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
  this.classList.remove("silk")
})

div1.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  this.innerHTML = (e.clientX + " "  + e.clientY);
})
```

```css
div {
  height:200px; 
  width:200px; 
  border:2px solid #000; 
  background:green; 
  display:inline-block; 
  margin:20px;
}
div.silk {background:cornsilk; }
```

```html
<div id="div1">onmousemove</div>
```

For your information but please use my version, here is a fixed version of your code.

Note I pass the event to the function and it is picked up as ev - not recommended since it is already available IN the function

```js
function fifa(ev){ // event passed as ev
  ev.target.style.background = "cornsilk"; // the div is the event target
  ev.target.innerHTML = (ev.clientX + " "  + ev.clientY); 
}
```

```css
div {
  height:200px; 
  width:200px; 
  border:2px solid #000; 
  background:green; 
  display:inline-block; 
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onmousemove="fifa(event)">onmousemove</div>
```

Comment: Also, my example should work. See this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove

Comment: Thanks, but see the link I gave you above. If the code is running there, what is issue with mine that I posted here? :(

Comment: No, I changed my code (updated it in question), but still error is coming. Pl check.

Comment: Pl, could you suggest, how should I make change then, to make this working?

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML just change "ev" to event and it will work.

```
   <div id="div1" onmousemove="fifa(event)">onmousemove</div>
```