# TypeError: checked is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I've had a problem where I wrote a checked() function for the onchange of a checkbox:

```
<input
      type="checkbox"
      id = "checked"
      onchange="checked()"
    />
```

Here's my javascript:

```
const check = document.getElementById("checkbox")
const yes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")

function checked() {
  if (check.checked) {
    yes.innerHTML = "Yes"
  } else {
    yes.innerHTML = "No"
  }
}
```

Basically I want the span with the class of yes to change output depending on if the checkbox is checked or not (Says Yes or No)
However, when I inspect, it says "TypeError: checked is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.onchange" even though my javascript is perfectly linked to my HTML (I checked this with an alert).

How can I solve this?

Comment: your element id is "checked" not "checkbox". You should not use property names as a property values that could lead to confusion.

Comment: The error is due to the way inline listeners are handled (`checked` [refers to the `checked` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63119431/1169519) of the checkbox element). Change the name of the function. There will be more errors, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting checkbox by id `checkbox`, but in your input field, you put `id="checked"` which is incorrect, so you need to correct your id from `checked` to `checkbox`.

```
<input
      type="checkbox"
      id = "checkbox"
      onchange="checked()"
    />
```

You also need to change your function name from `checked` to another name (like `checkData` which is not similar with native values/functions) and then wrap your `document.getElementById` into your function

You should not use `getElementsByClassName` too, because it returns a list of elements and `innerHTML` does not work for those, so you need to select a particular element with `getElementById`

```
function checkData() {
  const check = document.getElementById("checkbox")
  const yes = document.getElementById("yes") //need to use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

  //if `yes` element is not there, we don't need to set `innerHTML`
  if(!yes) {
    return
  }

  if (check.checked) {
    yes.innerHTML = "Yes"
  } else {
    yes.innerHTML = "No"
  }
}
```

Remember to implement your `yes` element like this

```
<p id="yes"></p> //tag name is your choice
```

Technically, `checked` is the name of the value attribute on that input and it's not a function, so you cannot use it as a function name.

By the way, thank @Teemu for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for that good catch! I didn't test it, but after you mentioned it, I tried and modified it accordingly! Hopefully, this time it's all good! @Teemu

Comment: Yup, you also can get an individual element by classname by using `document.querySelector('.yes)`, if the use of the classname feels important. BTW. The onchange attribute is not yet fixed in your code, it's still `checked()`.

Comment: Hello, now that i've modified my code, it says: "TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at isChecked (script.js:5:19)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):43:11)" now that i've changed my functio name to isChecked()

Comment: You need to have `<p id="yes"></p>` in your HTML too. You can use any tag but `id="yes"` @NicoAsseo

Comment: Is it ok if this element is on another file? I'm working on forms with python and php right now. By the way, i've linked both files to the script.js

Comment: Yupp it should be fine, but if you're still worried about it, you can add `if(!yes) { return; }` (If that yes element is not there, you can skip `innerHTML` logic). By the way, I updated my answer too for your case @NicoAsseo

Answer (score 0):

> const check = document.getElementById("checkbox")

There is no such ID in your code named "checkbox". I think you want:

> const check = document.getElementById("checked")

Try giving your IDs, function names and input-types unique names so you won't get them mixed up with each other.

Comment: True, but the error isn't fired because of this.